# Can the Code Runner extension in VS Code use the selected kernel when running a piece of code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-code-runner

I'm new to programming and I'm setting up setting up Visual Studio Code to start learning some Python. I've got the following setup:

- MacOS 10.6.4 (I've got a system Python 2.7.16)
- installed Anaconda ('base' environment with Python 3.9.7 and 'Python310InclCoreDS' environment with Python 3.10.4)
- installed Visual Studio Code 1.66.2

  - ext: Python 2022.4.1
  - ext: Pylance 2022.4.3
  - ext: Jupyter Notebook Renderers v1.0.6
  - ext: Jupyter Keymap v1.0.0
  - ext: Jupyter 2022.3.1000901801
  - ext: Code Runner 0.11.7
  - ext: Black Formatter v2022.1.11231003

Now I have some trouble understanding the way the Code Runner extension picks it's Python version. See the screenshot below.

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

- Whenever I run a *complete* regular Python file (.py) the Python kernel picker works as expected and the selected Python version is used. (This scenario is not in the screenshot.)
- Whenever I run a *code cell* in a Jupyter notebook using the "Execute Cell" button the Jupyter kernel picker works as expected and the selected Python version is used. (This scenario is shown in my screenshot in red.)
- Whenever I select a *piece of code* using Code Runner in either a regular Python file (.py) or a Jupyter notebook the kernel pickers don't work as expected. I've noticed it will use my system Python 2.7.16 if terminal.integrated.inheritEnv=True. (This scenario is shown in my screenshot in blue.) It will use my Python 3.9.7 Anaconda environment when terminal.integrated.inheritEnv=False. (This scenario is not in the screenshot.)

Now I wonder: can Code Runner when running a *piece of code* also use the selected kernel (either when executing a piece of a .py file, or when executing a piece of a Jupyter notebook)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be related to the default Python interpreter used by code-runner, which you can change in setting.json.

You can refer to this [page](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/604) on github for more related information.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me! This pointed me in a direction I already explored: editing the Code-runner Executor Map and changing the Python value to `"python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName"`. What I figured out additionally, is that Code-runner doesn't use the kernel-picker from the Jupyter extension. Instead, it always uses the kernel-picker from the Python extension. This got me confused about what was exactly going on.

Comment: @luukburger Unfortunately, I can't even use code-runner in the jupyter file. It will prompt me that "NameError: name 'null' is not defined", so I can't reproduce your problem. There is also very little related content in GitHub. After all, this is not an official extension of Microsoft

Comment: I think that's because you press the top-right play button for the entire .ipynb file? This doesn't work, because Code-runner doesn't trigger ipython but python. What does work for me, is selecting a piece of code in a code-cell and right-click "Run Code", but as said: it won't use the selected kernel from the Jupyter extension but the one from the Python extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the [Executor Map of Code Runner](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration):

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
  "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName"
}
```

Quoting [@Luukburger](/users/2977092):

> Apart from that, Code Runner always uses the kernel selected in the Python extension, never the one from the Jupyter extension.